# combining two css settings into one

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
.transaction-info {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.order-info {
    padding-left: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

and I'd like to combine it as one, how do I do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go.

```
.transaction-info, .order-info { 
      display: inline-block; 
      margin-bottom: 20px; 
 }

.order-info {
      padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Instead of rewriting the same properties in different selectors, you can declare the selectors using a `,` and than declare the common properties with equal values in that, rest, which are unique to other `class` can be declared separately, so here, as you have `display: inline-block;` and `margin-bottom: 20px;` which are common properties with equal values, you can define them in common, rest which is `padding-left: 150px;` can be declared separately for `.order-info`

Comment: I still don't get it why people format their code that way... There are css minifiers for making the code unreadable.

Comment: The reason here is vertical comparison with the OP's question about "How to combine it". No purpose to minify or format, etc. Just that OP gets to know how it is done.

Comment: Ok happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.transaction-info, .order-info 
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.order-info 
{
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.transaction-info, .order-info {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.order-info {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: How is that any different from @Nathan Lee 's answer?

Comment: you need comma to separate classes

Comment: You are missing a comma between your two classes. The way you did it, is saying .order-info is a child of .transaction-info

Comment: We are trying to help and people are down voting us. Its just I missed one `comma`. This is weird.